# Put all opened org mode files in a list to be used eventually with helm lists

Tags: list, emacs, org-mode, emacs-helm

I am trying to put all (opened) org files in a list so I could add them to helm-projectile-switch-to-file lists.

I was able to get to this code:

```
  (->> (buffer-list)
       (--select (with-current-buffer it
                   (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)))
       (mapc #'kill-buffer))
```

but this kills the buffers instead of putting them in an aggregated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to kill the buffers, I suggest not applying `kill-buffer` to each element. Other than that, you pretty much got everything done already. Here's a version that does not require any external libraries:

```el
(seq-filter '(lambda (buffer)                                                                                                                                                            
               (with-current-buffer buffer
                 (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)))
            (buffer-list))
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I tried applying this to helm-projectile list: (add-to-list helm-source-projectile-buffers-list '(lambda (buffer) (with-current-buffer buffer (derived-mode-p 'org-mode))) (buffer-list)) but that gave errors. I don't know how to correctly add the list of open org-files to the helm-projectile-switch-to-buffer list.

Comment: It looks like you forgot the `(seq-filter ` part at the beginning. But also, `add-to-list` is only for adding a single element. Try `(setq helm-source-projectile-buffers-list (append helm-source-projectile-buffers-list (seq-filter...)))` instead.

Comment: I still don't see org-files that are open listed along other project files when calling helm-projectile-switch-to-buffer.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that - the above code gets you the list of buffers you're after, but I have no experience with helm-projectile.